# How do I encode a : in a url?

Tags: urlencode, url-encoding

I need to send a get request where the last part of the url is a json value. I have encoded the following `{"period":"600s"}` to use on multiple different sites, however they all come up with the same result where the `:` is not decoded.

The encoded url: `stickiness=%7B%22period%22%3A%22600s%22%7D`.

Its result when I enter it into my browser: [image]

So how do I encode a `:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%3A` **is** the encoding of `:`. `:` is reserved in URIs for designating the port number (e.g. `google.com:443` manually specifies to use port `443`, the default `HTTPS` port). If you want to include a `:` in a URI, it must be [precent-sign-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), which is what the `%3A` is. It can't be decoded in the URL bar because it would violate the reserved purpose of the `:` character.

Comment: So does that mean I can't have an encoded `:` in a url, or just that it will work but it won't show the `:` as itself, but as the encoded character?

Comment: you can have *only* an encoded `:` (`%3A`). " just that it will work but it won't show the : as itself, but as the encoded character?" yes.

Comment: Okay thanks, my request wasn't working the way I expected it to and I presumed that the encoding was the reason. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The colon character is not decoded in the browser as it belong to [the reserved characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters) that already have an explicit meaning in URLs elsewhere - in this case separating the protocol from the hostname and the port after the hostname.

The relevant standard is [RFC 1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt), page 3:

> Many URL schemes reserve certain characters for a special meaning:
>      their appearance in the scheme-specific part of the URL has a
>      designated semantics. If the character corresponding to an octet is
>      reserved in a scheme, the octet must be encoded.  The characters ";",
>      "/", "?", ":", "@", "=" and "&" are the characters which may be
>      reserved for special meaning within a scheme. No other characters may
>      be reserved within a scheme.
>
> Usually a URL has the same interpretation when an octet is
>      represented by a character and when it encoded. However, this is not
>      true for reserved characters: encoding a character reserved for a
>      particular scheme may change the semantics of a URL.
>
> Thus, only alphanumerics, the special characters "$-_.+!*'(),", and
>      reserved characters used for their reserved purposes may be used
>      unencoded within a URL.